# Memorizing a complex page state with url hash with Backbone.Router

Tags: javascript, url, backbone.js

I am currently trying to do what's written in the title :) but can't find a good/clean way to do it ...

Here is the problem :

I have a page with a map, with objects that you can display by clicking on them. This map also has a toolbar, that you can use to hide/show some categories of objects, and other similar stuff.

Currently I am using `Backbone.Router` and assign a permalink to those objects through url hash, e.g. `www.mysite.com/index/#/orange/1` -> `"show orange number 1"`. But now, I would also like to save the map toolbar state in the url, and I would like everything to be handled with the same router ! So the best thing would be to have several hashes, e.g. `www.mysite.com/index/#/orange/1#/show/bananas#/hide/apples`, -> `"show orange number 1 - display all bananas - hide apples"` but I know that it isn't possible ...

So, does anybody have an idea, how I could make this complex state appear in the url, and be handled by a Backbone router ? How can I handle it a clean/simple way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know backbone but regarding the URL I'd do something like:

```
#/orange/1/banana/all/apple/none
```

This places the noun (object name) first and the command (N, all, none) second, in pairs.

Comment: that's a rather good idea ... and that would actually work with Backbone router. However, I wonder how it would work with more complicated state, for example search results from the toolbar `#/orange/1/banana/search/green+africa` ? Well, I guess that I have do define a hash format in that case, so basically hack my own thing.

Comment: That's the way I did it, but it turned out to be just too complicated in the end, so I gave up the whole thing.